# Using WHERE LIKE for results encoded in JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, json

Just like to know if it is possible to do queries on sql table results encoded in JSON?

I have a table value as follows:

```
column name: keywords 
column result: ["furniture","home furnishings","opening sale","home furnitures","sale and promotions"]
```

So i'm looking at

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE '%home%' AND keywords LIKE '%furnitures%'";
```

***Is it possible?*** I tried a query but the results shown do not show accurately.

Comment: Your query will work since both `%home%` and `%furnitures%` will match your JSON string. You haven't said what the problem with accuracy is.

Comment: @Mike W Oh okay. Thanks Mike, I got it. It was an eror over at my query that actually cost the inaccuracy.